# Passing variables between components without using @Input decorator in Angular 2

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I want pass the variable element obtained when the click event is trigerred in 'a' tag to the below component 'clr-modal'. I cant take that as input in 'clr-modal' component because I cant edit it. I need some hack so that i can do it html itself or any hack to do it apart from passing it as input to the nested component.

My code:

```
`<div class="card-block">
             <ul *ngFor="let element of inprogArr; trackBy: elementFn" class="list">
               <li>
                  <a (click)="opened=true; setval(element);">{{element.entry}}</a>
                  <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="opened">
                   <h3 class="modal-title">{{element.entry}}</h3>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Description :&emsp;{{element.entryDesc}}</p>
                    <br>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button (click)="moveInOn(element); opened=false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" >Move to Ongoing</button>
                   <button (click)="moveInCo(element); opened=false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Move to Completed</button>
                   </div>
                    </clr-modal>

               </li>
            </ul>

        </div>`
```

Comment: If you can't edit `clr-modal` how is it going to handle something you "pass" to it?

Comment: If you just want the `clr-modal` templat to have access to `element` it should already be able to use the one from the `*ngFor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass the element to the modal component. Because the `clr-modal` is making use of `ng-content` you are able to just reference the elements that exist in your current component. You should update your view to just define the modal once and then use a single property to hold the data of the currently opened modal like so:

```
<div class="card-block">
    <ul *ngFor="let element of inprogArr; trackBy: elementFn" class="list">
        <li>
            <a (click)="opened=true; setval(element); modalElement = element">{{element.entry}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="opened">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalElement?.entry}}</h3>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Description :&emsp;{{modalElement?.entryDesc}}</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button (click)="moveInOn(modalElement); opened=false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Move to Ongoing</button>
                <button (click)="moveInCo(modalElement); opened=false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Move to Completed</button>
            </div>
    </clr-modal>
</div>
```

## [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/K1WFcl5BP2Q9648zD66W)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my problem. Can you tell me more about modalElement or some resource that would be helpful to know more.

Comment: @darsh `modalElement` is not part of the angular framework. It is just a variable that I created on the component by assigning it in the template. It is equivalent to making a property on the component and referencing it in the view. I could have called it `fooBar` and this would have worked as well. I needed to call it something other than `element` however because a variable with that name was already in use inside the `*ngFor`

Comment: Another thing. Why do you use '?' like modalElement?.entry and not just modalElement.entry. Thank you!

Comment: The `?.` is called the Elvis operator and it short-circuits if any value along the chain is `null` and just returns `null`. This is import for this example because `modalElement` is not defined until the first list item is clicked.